# Find all database names on a Netezza server

Tags: excel, vba, odbc, database-connection, netezza

I want to find out the names of all DB instances on a Netezza DB server. I am using the following code:

```
Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRec = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

objConn.open "Driver={NetezzaSQL};servername=xx.xx.xx.xx;port=5480;database=_v_database;username=pankaj;password=xxx_333"
sqlQuery="select database from _v_database"
objRec.open sqlQuery, objConn

value = objRec.fields.item(0)
msgbox Value
```

I am able to connect to individual DBs and able to fetch data. However, when I try to run the above code I am getting "Database _V_DATABASE does not exist" error. Can anyone help me in finding all the instances on a particular server - doesn't have to be strictly in VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution - I used `database=SYSTEM` instead of `database=_v_database` in the connection string.

```
Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRec = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

objConn.open "Driver={NetezzaSQL};servername=xx.xx.xx.xx;port=5480;database=SYSTEM;username=pankaj;password=xxx_333"
sqlQuery="select database from _v_database"
objRec.open sqlQuery, objConn

value = objRec.fields.item(0)
msgbox Value
```